# will lots of people on website overload database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, multiple-users

I have a website run by php. I have about 80 users that will be signing up within a hour period.

my question is are there any problems that could occur when having lots of people accessing my database all at once?

I mean 80 users is a lot for me, and if some of you people that have way more than that are laughing at me, how many people would it take to mess up a database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It all depends on the speeds of your hardware and what your code does, but 80 users in an hour is nothing. Any system should be able to cope with that.

Comment: It depends on the hardware, but 80 is not much, even a relatively slow (P4, 512MB RAM) server would be enough (or your laptop). Also, What do you do in the code? If we are talking about 1000+ inserts for a single user, than it could be problematic.

Comment: Just logging in? No. It depends on how much you're pulling from the database per request. If you're pulling thousands of records per request or something, maybe.

Comment: so the users are creating accounts and the php inserts one row of 7 columns into my database

Comment: Shouldn't worry about it. If You didn't make a critical mistake in the code to affect performance, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: OK. Thanks! thats a relief

Comment: You can determine these things yourself, approximately. Fire up a tool like Apache Bench and see how long it takes to display a page - make sure you are on a reasonably fast connection. On a simple VPS, a well-written PHP page will take fractions of a second to process (the request/response time, and the loading of CSS/JS/images are additional, but are not much more). You can simulate a certain number of users simultaneously too. That said, your load is very light - 80 users per hour is just over one per minute on average, which any server will be fine with.

Comment: thanks @halfer. that helps a lot. i didn't know I could use Apache Bench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a tool like [apachebench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) to check.  Then you could use tools like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) (or memcachedb if you needed persistence) to dial down the mysql queries.  I would also set up mysql slow query logging.